# extract part of a number - javascript

Tags: javascript, numbers

Beginner in javascript, I need to code a fairly simple task:

Extract a portion of a number.
I need only 2 digits: the one immediately before and the one immediately after the decimal separator.

```
Example
Number: 443.12
Extract: 3.1
```

Comment: `string.prototype.IndexOf` will give you the location of the decimal point.  After that, you can use `subStr`, `subString` or `[]` (bracket notation) to get the string character you need.

Comment: Regular expression would get you the parts you want or you can do a split with array functions (though not as elegantly) or you can use indexOf and string functions. Try something first then ask specific questions on what you have tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
var num = 443.12;
num.toString().substr(num.toString().indexOf('.') - 1, 3);
```

Hope this works :)

Answer (score 0):

This would be a simple approach

```
var number = 443.12;
var suffix = parseInt((number - parseInt(number)) * 10);
var copy = number / 10;
var prefix = parseInt((copy ) - parseInt(copy )) * 10);
var extract = prefix + (suffix/10);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var n = 443.12 + ''; // make it a string
var i = n.indexOf('.');
if (i!==-1) // make sure it contains a .
    console.log(n.substr(i-1, 3));
```